# Turning Web Application Projects into separate DLLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

I converted my web site project into a web application project but now when I want to release it to the server, how do I get it to build separate DLLs?

Comment: Look in the bin folder. It should contain one dll per one project

Answer (score 3):

You will only get a single dll for a web application project.  You can't do separate dlls like a web site.

To publish the project with bare minimum files necessary, right click on the Project > Publish.  You can export it to a local directory and then transfrer it to the server from there.

Comment: You can also publish using FTP or Web Deploy, using the same menu command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Web Deployment Projects 2010 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24509). With it, you'll have the following options when it comes about compiling you web application:

1. A single assembly for the entire Web site.
2. One assembly per content folder.
3. A single assembly for all UI components.
4. An assembly for each compiled file in the Web site.

I think the options #2 and #4 can fit your needs.

For more information please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx.